# Autocorrelation (acf) and Partial Autocorrelation (pacf) to identify Box-Jenkins models

Tags: time-series, econometrics, acf-pacf, box-jenkins

Can you help me to identify which Box-Jenkins models in these pictures?

I have read behavior ACF and PACF to identify whether this is AR, MA, ARMA or ARIMA but I'm so confused because none of the books that I read have an example that looks like this. I'm using Log returns for this data and this is test In Level.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain the nature of the data (what is this variable representing?), Is it monthly data? Include a plot of the time series.

Comment: Monthly data with no obvious seasonality and almost no significant autocorrelations (well, one, but allow for multiple testing too). I am no expert but looks very like white noise to me.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen 49 observations from 1/2016 to 1/2020 looks like monthly data to me.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes , it's a monthly data . I'm about to comparing volatility of cryptocurrencies and fiat currencies , those are Bitcoin and Ethereum  Closed prices .  Should I use daily data ? I'm so frustating since this is for my undergraduate thesis :')

Comment: @NickCox  yeah , that's why it confusing me . but I've tried with price and it goes pretty fine. And I found ARIMA (4,1,4) for Bitcoin. do you think it's okay If I use Raw price data ? or should I change monthly data with something ? I calculated my data with excel using formula =ln(p/pn-1)

Comment: Sorry but I (can) have no idea what you should be doing or what's a good path for your project. I don't work in economics or finance for a start. You need local advice.

Comment: Okay, it's okay. BTW Thank you for your response!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen , I just uploaded plot there .